# glib version is not the minimum required

Tags: gcc, debian, glib

I'm having trouble compiling a program with gcc that includes glib.h on a Debian 9 i386 machine.  gcc is telling me that my glib version does not meet the minimum value.

```
GLIB_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED must be >= GLIB_VERSION_2_26
```

The GLIBC version on the machine is 2.24

```
# ldd --version
ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.24-11+deb9u3) 2.24
```

But I installed the -dev package and it says that 2.50.3-2 was installed

```
# apt install libglib2.0-dev
...
Get:1 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch/main i386 libglib2.0-dev i386 2.50.3-2 [3,091 kB]
...
```

However, the error persists.  I was able to compile this project without problems on a Debian 9 x86_64 machine.  What else needs installed for this to work?

Answer (score 5):

`GLIB_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` is not the same as the installed GLib version. `GLIB_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` is a macro which is defined by the program you’re trying to compile, to tell GLib the minimum version of GLib it depends on, so that GLib can warn you if the program uses symbols introduced in a later version of GLib. See [its documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Version-Information.html#GLIB-VERSION-MIN-REQUIRED:CAPS).

The `GLIB_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED must be >= GLIB_VERSION_2_26` error message is emitted if `GLIB_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` is set to a version < 2.26. This is a bug in the program you’re trying to compile: find where it defines `GLIB_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` and bump that dependency to ≥ 2.26.

> The GLIBC version on the machine is 2.24
>
> ```
> # ldd --version
> ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.24-11+deb9u3) 2.24
> ```

That’s irrelevant. GLib (a C utility library) is not the same thing as glibc (the system C runtime library).

Comment: All I'm doing is including glib.h so I can use hash tables.  Exact same code on x86_64 but no issues.  Where would it be defined so I can bump it up?  And if I installed 2.50 shouldn't it already be set?

Comment: `GLIB_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` is defined in the code of the project you are compiling, not in GLib itself. I can’t help you find it in the project. `git grep` or `ack` would be useful.